# Dynamic charts with jquery and swfobject

Tags: jquery, swfobject

I have a chart loaded with swfobject. How can I load the variables dynamically? As in changing the values without reloading the swf? Here is my js:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
          "/media/open-flash-chart.swf", "chart-demo",
          "400", "250", "9.0.0", "/media/expressInstall.swf",
          {"data-file":"{% url monitor-graph %}"} );
```

Im using django, so I grab the data from the view pointing at "monitor-graphs". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can use ajax to reload the data:

```
tmp = findSWF("chart-demo");
x = tmp.reload("data.php?chart=2");
```

A [demo of it is here](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-js-ajax-2.php) and an example of setting single values can be [found here](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-js-2.php).